# using velodyne(HDL-32E)

Tags: ros, network, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, We have a velodyne(HDL-32E) and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, groovy user.
I followed this velodyne tutorial.
[Getting Started with the Velodyne HDL-32E]

In this tutorial, we had to set up network like this.

```
1. sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.3.100
2. sudo route add 192.168.XX.YY eth0
```

And here is problem.
It has worked well just for seconds,
after then Ubuntu showed "Wired Connection - Disconnected" Message and
velodyne package stop working.

I saw my route table by "route",
192.168.17.171(our devices IP) has been exsisting for a seconds, and then disappeared.

Do I have to do that progress(sudo ifconfig....)?
Although I have 1 LAN Card, why I need to add velodyne's IP to routing table.
And after modifying routing table, why this table has not maintained forever.

Please help us.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/113091/using-velodyne(hdl-32e)/) by [Juni](https://answers.ros.org/users/8961/juni/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2013-12-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Juni](https://answers.ros.org/users/8961/juni/) on 2013-12-26**:
Thank you for answering.
It is working well.
^^

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't have time to write a more substantial answer at the moment, but you should disable Ubuntu's network manager before you use the command line tools for managing the network interfaces, you can disable it per port also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/266767/how-to-stop-networkmanager

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2013-12-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The previous answer works.

Here you have an alternative. If you don't want to stop the network manager, you can also make the steps 1 and 2 with an interface, using the tool Network of the Ubuntu. You can find it in the applications menu of Ubuntu.

You go to the options of the wired connexion, menu IPv4, then Manual method instead of automatic one, and insert the IP (step 1) and the route (step 2).

This way your configuration will be permanent without stopping the network manager.

---

Originally posted by [marilia15](https://answers.ros.org/users/5506/marilia15/) with karma: 104 on 2014-03-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kailegh](https://answers.ros.org/users/21460/kailegh/) on 2016-06-06**:
I was going to say the same, this answer works fine for me.